# Access Laravel Sanctum in Android Studio Emulator

Tags: laravel, android-emulator, laravel-sanctum

In getting a 400 error code when trying to make a request from an Android Studio Emulator.

In Laravel I have this config for Sanctum:

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 'localhost,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1,beexlaravel.lndo.site,10.0.2.2')),
```

In using Lando dev for the docker environment and the vhost it expose is **beexlaravel.lndo.site**
But the problem is that when I trying to access this domain from the Emulator it can not resolve the domain, that's why I add the **10.0.2.2** in the config file, but still get the 400 error.

In the **cors** config file I had the **supports_credentials** set it to **true** and '**allowed_origins**' => ['*'].

And I also at the **referer** header set it to all of the domains listed.

I not sure if there is a way to add a wildcard (dev porpuse) to the **stateful** list, I tried with * .

Should I edit the Emulator host file, to resolved the **beexlaravel.lndo.site** ?
Or is there any other config that I missing on?

Comment: you cant use cookie session in a mobile app. use tokens instead.

Comment: @TEFO does that mean that you cannot use Sanctum for a mobile app? Or is there anything specific that needs to be setup differently with sanctum?

Comment: @InigoEC sure can, but use sanctum for apis. and its in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#mobile-application-authentication